# How to run python + google app engine application locally but pointing to live google datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing an application using python and google app engine. It is using local database. I want to run my code which points to google live datastore. Will you please guide how to configure my app to point to live google datastore instead of local so that I can check my code against live datastore?

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool available called the Remote API that should provide the functionality you're asking about. The documentation there should provide you with what you need to interact with the actual datastore. It's available for other languages as well, but here is the link to the Python documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi

I have a small amount of experience with the Go interface.

Comment: A key thing to point out with the Remote API is that it can be used say locally for testing OR could be used from a different hosting platform to get access to Datastore, such as connections from Compute Engine if you were doing maybe batch processing of your Datastore data. I don't think this comes across clearly in the docs.

Comment: I followed the link but I am only able to access live datastore from terminal.

Comment: Response which I get after following the link :-                                     Using the Remote API Shell :-                              C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine>remote_api_shell.py -s demo11-1147.appspot.com
App Engine remote_api shell
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
The db, ndb, users, urlfetch, and memcache modules are imported.
s~demo11-1147>

Comment: Using the Remote API in a local client:-    D:\java_workspace\python_demo\Demo\src>python client.py demo11-1147
Key('Employee', 5629499534213120)
Key('Employee', 5639445604728832)
Key('Employee', 5649391675244544)
Key('Employee', 5722646637445120)
Key('__Stat_Kind_IsRootEntity__', 'Employee')
Key('__Stat_Kind__', 'Employee')
Key('__Stat_PropertyName_Kind__', 'date_Employee')
Key('__Stat_PropertyName_Kind__', 'firstName_Employee')
Key('__Stat_PropertyType_Kind__', 'Date/Time_Employee')

Comment: If I run the application and check the environment variable os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine/'), it gets to false, means app is running on local. I want my code to run on local but accessing live datastore.

Comment: The terminal usage they provide examples for is just to get you up and running and to experiment with the capabilities. Just read further down the page in the "Using the Remote API in a local client" section if you want to use the remote API within your application. Your code will need some changes.

Comment: The value of the SERVER_SOFTWARE environment variable will not change because of the presence of the remote API, that will always be set to having the the"Development" prefix locally and "Google App Engine" when deployed. If you want to have the same code work in both local and deployed contexts, one approach might be to use that check to determine whether of not the remote API needs to be enabled, since in the deployed environment you can just use the normal interface.